# Как правильно сказать: "Различны ПО своей индивидуальности" или "Различны В своей индивидуальности"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

1. Различны по своей индивидуальности.
2. Различны в своей индивидуальности.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (зеленая галочка).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Различны по своей индивидуальности
> 2. Различны в своей индивидуальности

По-моему, плохи оба варианта.

Само слово ***индивидуальность*** уже предполагает отличие одного индивидуума от другого. Зачем тогда нужно слово *"различны"*?

Answer (score 0):

Верное управление: *Различны **в** своей индивидуальности*.

В словаре:

> Различный -- неодинаковый в чем-л., несходный, разный.

Слово *индивидуальность* уже содержит идею исключительности личности, поэтому приведенное вами предложение содержит плеоназм.

Корректный вариант:

> - Различны в характерах.